# Design a circuit with range of -10 to +10V

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, plc

[image]

I'm using a PLC for a project, the output from the PLC DAC is 0-10V but I need to scale it to -10 to +10 V (similar to the graph). Obviously I need to build a circuit with an opamp, I'm thinking of something like this. [image] 
Could anyone help with the values of the resisters I should use? Would this work? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest approach is to set Rf = R1 = 10K and leave R2 in the drawer. You'll need a Vref of 10.0V. All easily available parts.

If you want to use a lower voltage reference than 10V, you'll have to attenuate the voltage from the DAC.

Comment: +1, worth a mention V+ and V- need to be wider that +-10V by at least however close the op-amp can drive the output to the rails. Check the data-sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I've simulated the values and it worked!, and for the V+ and V- it's 15V (I'm using op-amp 741).